# Sino-Korean numerals

Tags: code-golf, number, conversion, unicode

The Korean language has two sets of numerals, a native Korean numerals and Sino-Korean numerals.

The native Korean numerals are mostly used for numbers under 100, such as age and time.

The Sino-Korean numeral system, which is based on the Chinese numeral system as its name says, is used in most of the time.

It uses 4-digit group system rather than western 3-digit group system. For example, 123456789 can be grouped into 1, 2345, 6789 in Sino-Korean system.

All 4 digits in group have their own place names.

- Thousands: 천
- Hundreds: 백
- Tens: 십
- Ones: 일, but not used.

Also, for every 4 digits, suffixes are coming along with numbers.

- 10^0: none, obviously.
- 10^4: 만
- 10^8: 억
- 10^12: 조
- 10^16: 경
- 10^20: 해
- ...

So, the number '123456789' in Sino-Korean is "일억 이천삼백사십사만 육천칠백팔십구".

## Goal and Rules

Your goal is to convert given integer to Sino-Korean numeral.

- Numbers are grouped into 4 digits from behind.
- Whitespaces are inserted every 4 digits (from behind).

  > 4321 -> 사천삼백이십일
  >   30723231 -> 삼천칠십이만 삼천이백삼십일
- '일'(1) is omitted except if it is last digit of its group.

  > 1111 -> 천백십일 **(not 일천일백일십일)**
  >  
  >   137161293 -> 일억 삼천칠백**십**육만 **천**이백구십삼
- There is only one exception, 10000 is not "일만", but "만".

  > 18210 -> 1 8210 -> 만 팔천이백십 **(not 일만 팔천이백십)**
- Standard `code-golf` rules are applied.

#### Table of Sino-Korean Digits

```
+-------+-------------+
| Digit | Sino-Korean |
+-------+-------------+
|     0 |          영 |
|     1 |          일 |
|     2 |          이 |
|     3 |          삼 |
|     4 |          사 |
|     5 |          오 |
|     6 |          육 |
|     7 |          칠 |
|     8 |          팔 |
|     9 |          구 |
+-------+-------------+
```

#### Input and Output

Input is integer \$N, 0 \leq N < 10^{24}\$

Output is UTF-8 formatted Sino-Korean numeral.

## Examples

- (Input) -> (Output)
- 0 -> 영
- 1 -> 일
- 10 -> 십
- 101 -> 백일
- 301821 -> 삼십만 천팔백이십일
- 10282714472 -> 백이억 팔천이백칠십일만 사천사백칠십이
- 999999999999999999999999 -> 구천구백구십구해 구천구백구십구경 구천구백구십구조 구천구백구십구억 구천구백구십구만 구천구백구십구

---

This is `code-golf`, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: `1111 -> 천백십일 (not 일천일백일십일)` but Firefox show the second one for 1111 [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdwvmR)

Comment: @tsh Forms like "일천일백일십일" can be used but only in special areas like finance for prevent counterfeit. It is omitted in daily life usage.